# Random Variable convergence in $L^{q}$ space, then the conditional expectation also converges in $L^{q}$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $q\geq 1$, and $X_{n}, X\in L^{q}$ are random variables in probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in $L^{q}$, then for every sub $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, I have $E[X_{n}|\mathcal{G}] \rightarrow E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ in $L^{q}$.

Comment: I define $Y_{n}=E[X_{n}|\mathcal{G}]$ and $Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, they are both in $L_{q}$ by Jensen's inequality but I fail to prove convergence in $L^{q}$. I begin with definition $\int|Y_{n}-Y|^{q}d\mathbb{P}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$
be a sub $\sigma$-algebra. We recall Jensen inequality: For any convex
function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and any random
variable $\xi:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. If $E\left[\left|\varphi(\xi)\right|\right]<\infty$,
then $\varphi\left(E\left[\xi\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)\leq E\left[\varphi(\xi)\mid\mathcal{G}\right]$
(a.e.).

Let $p\in[1,\infty)$ be fixed. We go to show that for any $X\in L^{p}$,
we have $||E\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]||_{p}\leq||X||_{p}$. Let
$X\in L^{p}$ be given. Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be defined by $\varphi(x)=|x|^{p}$. Clearly $\varphi$ is convex
and $\varphi(X)$ is integrable. By Jensen inequality, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
|E\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]|^{p} & = & \varphi\left(E\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)\\
 & \leq & E\left[\varphi(X)\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\\
 & = & E\left[|X|^{p}\mid\mathcal{G}\right].
\end{eqnarray*}
Clearly $\Omega\in\mathcal{G}$, therefore 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int|E\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]|^{p}dP & \leq & \int_{\Omega}E\left[|X|^{p}\mid\mathcal{G}\right]dP\\
 & = & \int_{\Omega}|X|^{p}dP.
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that $||E\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]||_{p}\leq||X||_{p}$.

Comment: For your case, $||Y_n-Y||_p \leq ||X_n - X||_p \rightarrow 0$.